# showing $\int _a^b\left(f'\left(x\right)\right)dx\:=\:f\left(b\right)-f\left(a\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives, continuity

Let $f(x):[a,b]\to \mathbb R$, be  differentiable on $[a,b]$ (and continuous) so that $f'(x)$ is integrable on $[a,b]$.

I need to show that:
$$\int _a^b\left(f'\left(x\right)\right)\mathrm dx = f\left(b\right)-f\left(a\right)$$

my thought was to show that $f'$ is continuous, and then using the Fundamental theorem of calculus to complete the proof.

**but, is $f '(x)$ continuous on $(a,b)$?**

thanks

Comment: Do you think that every derivative is continuous ?

Comment: $f'$ need not be continuous in general.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo That's what he's asking

Comment: Your statement is true as long as $f'$ is Riemann integrable (see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part ). If you use the Lebesgue integral, it is also true if $f'$ is Lebesgue integrable, see e.g. here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813230/proving-the-mean-value-inequality-in-higher-dimensions-for-a-differentiable-func/813384#813384 (this is even in the case of Banach valued functions, but the proof works (even simpler) in the scalar case).

Comment: @leo Thank you for the notice. I was wrong, I meant _integrable_ instead of _continuous_.

Comment: thanks =] I know that not every derivative is continuous, but I wonder if an integrable(Riemann) derivative of a continuous function, is necessarily continuous...is it?

Comment: See J.L.Taylor [_Foundations of Analysis_](http://www.lemiller.net/media/classfiles/notes.pdf) (2011), p. 125, example 5.3.2.

Comment: No, a Riemann integrable derivative is not necessarily continuous.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez See my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be differentiable on $[a,b]$.

It is a fact that the following statement is **true**:

*for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta(x)>0$ so that $$\left|\sum_{i=1}^n f'(\xi_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})-(f(b)-f(a))\right|<\varepsilon$$ whenever $$a=x_0<x_1<\dots<x_{n-1}<x_n=b$$ and $$\xi_i \in [x_i-x_{i-1}]$$ with $$|x_i-x_{i-1}|<\delta(\xi_i)$$*

but the following is **false**:

*for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ (**not depending on $x$**) so that $$\left|\sum_{i=1}^n f'(\xi_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})-(f(b)-f(a))\right|<\varepsilon$$ whenever $$a=x_0<x_1<\dots<x_{n-1}<x_n=b$$ and $$\xi_i \in [x_i-x_{i-1}]$$ with $$|x_i-x_{i-1}|<\delta$$*

$$$$

In other words, one can always approximate $f(b)-f(a)$ by Riemann sums of $f'$ "pointwise" but cannot always do it "uniformly".

So your aim is hopeless if you just use the classical Riemann integral.

Comment: This is incorrect. The claim you state is false is in fact the definition of what it means for $f'$ to be Riemann integrable with integral equal to $f(b)-f(a)$.

Comment: I say that not every derivative is Riemann integrable.

Comment: Yes, but the OP is assuming that $f'$ is integrable, so your answer isn't really an answer to the question which was asked.

Comment: Do you think that OP's "so that $f'(x)$ is integrable" is an assumption? It seems to me a consequence (if you are right, why doesn't OP use a simple _and_ ?).

Comment: Yes, it is ambiguous, but I think his/her comments make it clear this was meant as an assumption. But fair enough, I cannot remove my downvote unless the answer is edited.

Comment: OP wrote only one comment four hours after my answer $\dots$